# Have multiple tablix on same page in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

i have 5 different tablix that i want to show on the same page when i view the report. Currently i can just put Keep Together to True and keep first table on one page, but other tables are on next pages. 
I want to have all tables with data on same page and problem is my first table because is to long.

Comment: Set report interactive height to 0

Comment: Thank you :) This solved my problem

Comment: You are welcome